Webpack5 and Angular17 application - problem with image assets references
I've been migrating Angular application from Angular 11/Webpack 3/Node14 to Angular 17/Webpack 5/Node20.
I got stuck with the problem  that image references in Angular component do not get replaced to the references to bundled images (as it was before migration)
Thus, for example status-processed-icon16.svg is still injected in app.bunlde.js as it was in the component:
["src","../../../img/status-processed-icon-16.svg","width","16px","height","16px"]

but it must be injected as assets/status-processed-icon-169cf5bb34d4a87e23bf4f.svg like Webpack3 successfully did  before migration. The .svg resource itself as you can see is bundled correctly to /assets folder with the hash.  Moreover when the same icon is referenced from CSS, it is displayed correctly (probably because it gets processed by css-loader which is able to do this transformation without problems)
But when it referenced as
<img src="../../../img/status-processed-icon-16.svg"     width="16px"     height="16px" />
of Angular component, 'src' is still raw and therefore leads to 404(not found) error.
Having run dev server on the pre-migated  instance (which works correctly) I could see that this file is referenced with a comment  like HTML_loader__import__4 , then require() of the bundled asset goes. It led me to conclusion that HTML loader is the culprit.
I tried for several days many approaches found on SO - use different loaders with different options, use or do not use asset resources (recommended for Webpack5) - with no avail. The task is very simple - to replace raw references in app.bundle.js files to their analogs from /asset folder, but how to get it done - I am desperate to come up with any solution in terms of Webpack 5.
Of course the issue occurs for all images referenced in a similar way.
Webpack configs are below, any help is appreciated.
webpack.base.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        alias: {
            jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
        }
    },
    
    
    module: {
        rules: [
        {       
            test: /\.(scss)$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },

            
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'assets/[name][hash][ext][query]'
                }
                
            },
            

            
            /*{
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                 options: {
                    name: 'assets/[name][hash][ext][query]',
                }
            }, -- if I enable this instead of asset/resource above I get weird files containing javascript 'requires' but having .svg or other image extensions, options/name is ignored, root folder anyway */
                    
            
            /*{
                test: /\.html$/,
                type: 'asset/source',               
                exclude: /index\.html/,
            }
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    minimize: false,
                    esModule: false // read on SO that it helps to process images - really it affects nothing
                }
            }, -- this block does nothing in fact, I can switch on html-loader or asset/resource or disable both - no effect*/

            
            
            

        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            './ClientApp',
            {}
        ),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(
        {  resourceRegExp: /^\.\/locale$/,
            contextRegExp: /moment$/ }),


        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: 'index.html'}),
        new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({outputPath: 'favicons', prefix: 'favicons'})
    ]
}

webpack.prod.config.js
const {merge} = require('webpack-merge');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.base.config.js');
const publicPath = process.env.PUBLIC_PATH || '/';
const publicDir = 'wwwroot';
const outputDir = path.resolve(__dirname, publicDir);
const AngularWebpackPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularWebpackPlugin;
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

//const tsi = require('tsimportlib');
//const linkerPlugin =  tsi.dynamicImport('@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel', module);


console.log('diagn:process.env.PUBLIC_PATH = ', process.env.PUBLIC_PATH);


module.exports = merge(baseConfig, {
    mode: 'production',
    
    context: __dirname + '/ClientApp',
    entry: {
        app: './index-aot.ts'
    },

    output: {
        filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
        chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
         assetModuleFilename: "[name][ext]",
        path: outputDir,
        publicPath
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                use: '@ngtools/webpack'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                  MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                  "css-loader"
                ]
            },



            /*{ 
                test: /\.mjs$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    compact: false,
                    plugins: [linkerPlugin.default],
                },
                resolve: {
                    fullySpecified: false
                }
            }*/



        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
                cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
                    preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }],
                }
            }),
            new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: { format: { comments: false, }, },
                extractComments: false,
            })
        ],
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    chunks: "all",
                    test: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                    name: "vendor",
                    enforce: true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'static/css/style[name].[hash:8].css',
            chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].[hash:8].css',
        }),
        new AngularWebpackPlugin({
                        tsconfig: './tsconfig-aot.json'
                })      
    ]
});


Thanks in advance!
